# Корректное управление объектами на форме и время жизни формы

Tags: c#, winforms, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, обработка-ошибок

Продолжаю изучать концепцию событий в c#. У меня есть следующий набор классов:

```
    class CustomTimer
    {
        private Timer timer;

        public delegate void DateAndTimeHandler(DateTime dateTime);
        DateAndTimeHandler dateOrTimeUpdated;

        public event DateAndTimeHandler DateOrTimeUpdated
        {
            add { lock (this) dateOrTimeUpdated += value; }
            remove { lock (this) dateOrTimeUpdated -= value; }
        }

        public CustomTimer()
        {
            int num = 0;
            TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(ProcessTime);
            timer = new Timer(tm, num, 0, 1000);

        }

        private void ProcessTime(object obj)
        {
            dateOrTimeUpdated?.Invoke(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    class SuperCore
    {
        public CustomTimer timer = new CustomTimer();
    }
```

И соответствующий код формы, которая является просто гипотетическим приложением и не несет никакого полезного функционала кроме как отображение текущей даты и времени на label1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string StringTime
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set { Invoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = value; }));}
    }

    SuperCore superCore = new SuperCore();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        superCore.timer.DateOrTimeUpdated += TimeUpdate;
    }

    void TimeUpdate(DateTime dt)
    {
        StringTime = dt.ToString();
    }
```

Иногда при закрытии формы возникает следующая ошибка:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: "Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен.
```

Имя объекта: "Form1"."
[image: Скриншот сообщения об ошибке]
Я понимаю, что форма уже успевает уничтожиться, а событие продолжает вызываться ядром и подписанты остаются. В подписанном методе происходит обновление свойства формы StringTime и изменение текста label1, которого уже нет.
Конечно, я могу просто игнорировать подобного рода ошибки, обернув в подобную конструкцию:

```
public string StringTime
{
    get { try { return label1.Text; } catch { return ""; }; }
    set { try { Invoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = value; })); } catch { } }
}
```

Но меня это не до конца устраивает, так как это не совсем верное действие при такого рода ситуациях, ведь я просто игнорирую ошибку, а не исправляю ее источник.

**Вопрос: как мне решить мою проблему максимально корректно. Как сделать так, чтобы такой ошибки просто не возникало?**

Comment: Invoke(new Action(predicate)) Прикрепляет в поток формы, может его не надо туда вешать? пусть работает не в потоке формы.

Comment: @Dude36 А как Вы предлагаете решить эту проблему? В каком потоке он должен находится? В основном потоке приложения?

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант: проверять что форма все еще существует с помощью [`Control.IsDisposed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed?view=netframework-4.8), так обновление не будет выполняться после закрытия формы:

```
set { if(!IsDisposed) Invoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = value; }));}
```

<strike>Второй вариант:</strike> При закрытии формы ([`Form.FormClosed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed?view=netframework-4.8)) следует отписаться от события, чтобы освободить форму для сборщика мусора:

```
Closed += (s,e) => { superCore.timer.DateOrTimeUpdated -= TimeUpdate;}
```

Сама по себе отписка не сработает, т.к. `Timer` будет продолжать вызывать метод.

Третий: использовать [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=System.Windows.Forms.Timer&x=0&y=0), добавить его в список элементов формы, так он будет очищаться вместе с формой и проблема не возникнет.

Comment: Спасибо, первые два способа отлично подходят. А существует ли возможность как-то автоматизировать отписку от событий при закрытии формы. Например, чтобы все подписанты были автоматически отписаны от событий? Еще вопрос про закрытие формы: во втором способе Вы используете FormClosed, а можно ли использовать FormClosing? Это принципиально или нет? Просто FormClosing вызывается же до закрытия формы, имеет смысл там отписаться. Или я не прав?

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect Насчет массовой отписки от всех внешних событий ничего умного в голову не приходит. Один из вариантов: делать как `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, т.е. добавлять свой компонент на форму и очищать его вместе с формой. Но для внешнего ресурса такой сценарий не подойдет.

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect По поводу `FormClosed` и `FormClosing` насколько я помню, оба события выполняются до очистки, т.ч. можно использовать любое из них. Как я понимаю, единственное отличие: возможность отмены в `FormClosing`. Впрочем, здесь могу ошибаться, лучше проверить на практике.

Comment: понял, буду пробовать насчет закрытия формы. Третий вариант не подходит, к сожалению, из-за подхода к проектированию приложения. Данный пример просто демонстрирует проблему. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Опять получил ту же ошибку! Начал использовать второй способ, все было отлично, но вот опять выскочила та же самая ошибка. В чем теперь то может быть проблема? Проверял, ошибка выскакивает и если использовать FormClosed и если использовать FormClosing.

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect Да, приношу извинения. Этот метод не сработает из-за синхронизации. Надежного способа остановить `System.Threading.Timer` извне я не нашел.

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect Если проблема не решена до конца, то, возможно, Вы поторопились принять ответ. Попробуйте снять галочку, уточнить вопрос и тогда может кто-нибудь предложит лучшее решение.

Comment: А если не использовать таймер, а просто создать поток, который спит 1 секунду а потом генерирует событие. Это может решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

вариант

```
if (!IsDisposed)
  Invoke(...
```

не всегда срабатывает

иногда при закрытии приложения Form1.IsDisposed = false, не разобрался точно, почему

вроде как лучше использовать

```
if (!IsDisposing)
  Invoke(...
```

но это тоже не гарантия

очевидно, эти две строки - не атомарная операция, после проверки и до вызова Invoke, IsDisposing может поменять
По крайней мере, у меня так периодически происходит

Отписка от события на FormClosing работает гарантированно